# Rails 3.2 - Disable CSRF Protection for controller action

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, controller, action, csrf

I have a controller named ProductsController, and I've created an action named **set_status** for the purpose of PUT API calls from a .NET client application. I have gotten everything set up correctly, but after sending a request, I receive a "Can't verify CSRF token authenticity" error. I have the following in my Application controller for CSRF protection:

```
protect_from_forgery
```

In order to bypass the CSRF protection, I've added the following to my Products controller:

```
skip_before_filter :set_status
```

After testing with this change, I still get the same error message. Based on my understanding, the above line of code should disable CSRF protection for the **set_status** action in the Products controller, but it does not seem to be working.

Does anyone have any insight on why this might not be working? Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I figured it out! Here's my code:

```
skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token, only: :set_status
```

I forgot that the **protect_from_forgery** statement creates methods of its own. One of those methods is verify_authenticity_token, and so it was much more straightforward than I thought. I was stuck before because I didn't have a verify_authenticity_token method, but I actually did because it's generated automatically.

For Rails 4+

```rb
skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token, only: :set_status
```

Comment: In more recent versions of rails use `skip_before_action` instead of `skip_before_filter`. (skip_before_filter has been deprecated)

Comment: In even more recent versions you can also use `skip_forgery_protection` (just a built-in wrapper of `skip_before_action`)